# Linux command echo files names until char

Tags: bash

Here is my code

```
 cd /bin/
 echo *xyz?2* | cut -f 1 -d '.'
```

Please, how can i change this command to display files without extension ?
Bests.

Comment: You want to strip extension from filenames or want to find filenames without extensions?

Comment: I want to modify this cmmand echo *xyz?2* to display files names begin with xyz and "2" at position five  (Without Extension).

Comment: Provide some examples of your filenames and expected output

Comment: xyz32281.raw xyz32406.jpg xyz32459.jpg xyz3252.raw xyz7214.raw xyz8286.raw

Comment: Output: xyz32281 xyz32406 xyz32459 xyz3252 xyz7214 xyz8286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the filenames into an array and then use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ arr=(xyz?2*); echo "${arr[*]%.*}"
xyz32281 xyz32406 xyz32459 xyz3252 xyz7214 xyz8286
```

Comment: can i change this command ? i want use only "echo" without variable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filenames don't have any whitespace or glob characters.

You can just use `printf '%s\n'` instead of `echo` in your command:

```
printf '%s\n' *xyz?2* | cut -f 1 -d '.'
```

```
xyz32281
xyz32406
xyz32459
xyz3252
xyz7214
xyz8286
```

If you must use `echo` then use `awk` as this:

```
echo *xyz?2* | awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print (split($i, a, /\./)==2 ? a[1] : $i)}'

xyz32281
xyz32406
xyz32459
xyz3252
xyz7214
xyz8286
```

This `awk` command iterated through each filename matched by glob pattern and splits each name by dot. If dot is found then first part is printed otherwise full filename is printed.

Comment: i have to use echo

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that all files of `echo *xyz?2*` are shown in one line. When the filenames are without spaces/newlines, you can fix this by moving them to different lines and joining theem again when finished.

```
echo *xyz?2* | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -f 1 -d '.' | tr '\n' ' '| sed '$s/ $/\n/'
```

You can do this a lot easier with `sed`:

```
echo *xyz?2* | sed 's/[.][^. ]*//g'
```